# Calling Groups of Elements of Matlab Arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm dealing with long daily time series in Matlab, running over periods of 30-100+ years. I've been meaning to start looking at it by seasons, roughly approximating that by taking 91-day segments of each year over the time period (with some tbd method of correcting for odd number of days in the year)

Basically, what I want is an array indexing method that allows me to make a new array that takes 91 elements every 365 elements, starting at element 1. I've been looking for some normal array methods (some (:) or other), but I haven't been able to find one. I guess an alternative would be to kind of iterate over 365-day segments 91 times, but that seems needlessly complicated.

Is there a simpler way that I've missed?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to extract elements 1-91, 366-457, 731-822, and so on?  I'm not sure that there is a way to do this with basic matrix indexing, but you can do the following:

```
days = 1:365;  %Create array ranging from 1 - 365
difference = length(data) - 365;    %how much bigger is time series data?
padded = padarray(days, [0, difference], 'circular'); %extend to fit time series
extracted = data(padded <= 91); %get every element in the range 1-91
```

Basically what I am doing is creating an array that is the same size as your time series data that repeats 1-365 over and over.  I then perform logical indexing on `data`, such that the padded array is less than or equal to 91.

As a more approachable example, consider:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
days = 1:5;
difference = length(x) - 5;
padded = padarray(days, [0, difference], 'circular');
extracted = x(padded <= 2);
```

`padded` then is equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `extracted` is going to be `[1, 2, 6, 7]`